# Did Gordo have anything to do with Simon's firm finding out that Danny was framed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-gift

In the movie The Gift, did Gordon ensure that Simon's firm got to know that he had framed Danny to get the promotion? In effect, did Gordon orchestrate Simon losing his job and his wife?

Comment: I think that, like other key points in the plot, it was left intentionally ambiguous.

Comment: The other key points were left ambiguous by Gordo not the director :). In this case it's the same guy, but you know what I mean.